# Why am I getting 500 error while trying to send emails to some domains?

Tags: spam-marked

Recently I've been seeing the following error while trying to send emails to some domains:

```
Final-Recipient: name@example.com
Original-Recipient: name@example.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mail.example.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 "The mail server detected your message as spam and
    has prevented delivery."
```

Neither my IP address nor my domain is blacklisted. The email is a simple test email without attachments or links.

What can I do or where can I get more information about this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First things first, double-check [MXToolBox](https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) to verify your domain is not blacklisted.

Do emails to other addresses return the same issue or is it localized to just that domain? What about other servers to that domain, do they have the same issue?

Unfortunately, some email providers have their own internal blacklist that is not reliant on any of the ones listed on MXToolBox.

To resolve this type of issue, you will have to contact the domain's email provider directly. Most of the time, they will be able to provide reasoning as to why your emails are marked as spam. Most commonly, SPF/DKIM/DNS records are missing, that can be checked at the [MXToolBox SPF](https://mxtoolbox.com/spf.aspx) checker.

Comment: The answer doesn't get better than Hayden's.